# Is it possible to unset a session variable with a specific and variable index?

Tags: php, session

Let's say I have this specific session variable, `$_SESSION['cart_'.$itemid]`.

Is it possible to sort all through session variable and find the once with index `'cart_'.$itemid` and unset them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$matches = preg_grep('/^cart_/', array_keys($_SESSION));
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    unset($_SESSION[$match]);
}
```

Comment: This script is like magic; It works perfectly! May I ask what your script does? How does it differ from using strpos($key, "cart_") === 0 or $getcartname = (explode('_', $key)); if($getcartname[0] == 'cart');

Comment: preg_grep applies a regex to each member of an array (the keys of $_SESSION in this case), and returns any matching elements into a new array. So `$matches` will contain ALL of the `cart_XXX` keynames in your session. Then a simple loop to unset each of those session variables.

Answer (score 7):

Sure.  You could do something like

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val) {
  // Look for "cart_" at the front of the array key
  if (strpos($key, "cart_") === 0) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
}
```

Or the same thing using `array_keys()`:

```
foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key) { 
  // Look for "cart_" at the front of the array key
  if (strpos($key, "cart_") === 0) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
}
```

**Addendum**

If I may make a design suggestion though, if you have the ability to change this structure I would instead recommend storing these cart items as an array.  The array then holds as values the item IDs contained inside.

```
// Updated after comments....
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
// Add to cart like this:
$_SESSION['cart'][$itemId] = $new_quantity;
```

This would make it easier to do things like:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item=>$quantity) {
  // process the cart    
}
```

Comment: maybe you should use === and not ==

Comment: Won't work.  Need to use `===` with strpos.  There's a [great big warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) about this on the manual page!

Comment: and much safer, so that you don't remove a variable called something like "cart_type" that you might use in the future you could explode by underscore and if the result has two elements, the first one being "cart" and the second one being an int value you then remove it

Comment: @mishu === fixed. Too early in the morning.

Comment: The script works..."temporarily". When I press the clear button, it displays blank, which is what Im aiming for, but when I press add, the former contents of the array appears. BTW what if Im going to store 3 2 variables in a session array? Currently I'm using them like this $_SESSION['cart_'.$itemid] = $itemqty. I also forgot that $itemid is a variable so there could be many different of them. If posting the whole script would help just ask.

Comment: @JohnSmith See edits above. If storing multiple quantities, it is better to use `$itemId` as a key of the $_SESSION['cart'] array.

Comment: @JohnSmith The clearing not happening is likely part of a different problem and should be asked as a different question.  Make sure all scripts call `session_start()`/

Answer (score 1):

There would only be one item stored in $*SESSION['cart*' . $itemId] unless you are varying the contents of $itemId.

Anyway, sure you can unset that:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart_' . $itemId])) { // don't need this if you are iterating through $_SESSION
  unset($_SESSION['cart_' . $itemId]);
}
```

Comment: The $itemid is indeed a variable. Sorry I forgot to post that. Im aimiing to remove all session variable with index starting at 'cart_'. The $itemid could be any alphanumeric value.