# How should I store shopping cart items?

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I'm writing a simple shopping cart in PHP, but I'm not quite sure how I should store the items a users selects to purchase. Should I use cookies? Of course, if I did use cookies, all I would store in the cookie is the item SKU and quantity. I wouldn't store the prices in the cookies, since the user could potentially change them.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: See the answers here for suggestions on how to store them in `$_SESSION` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610890/is-it-possible-to-unset-a-session-variable-with-a-specific-and-variable-index/7610928#7610928

Comment: @Michael - To make the shopping cart remain available to a visitor who is not logged in, I would need to use a cookie to link the guest to their shopping cart, right? Because doesn't a session variable get deleted after the visitor leaves the website? If storing the cart in a database, would it be better to use a three column table like user_id, item_id, and quantity, with one row in the table for each item the visitor has in their cart, or to have all the items and quantities in one column using a comma separated list or serializing it? Thank you!

Comment: To link a user who has left, you would need to serialize the cart and store it in a database, along with some value in the user's cookie that identifies them.  Or make sessions that never expire.  It's a lot more work to use the database to store individual cart values rather than a serialized string, but if you are going to do it that way, you may as well not bother with `$_SESSION` at all and instead just use the database for all of it.

Comment: Xeoncross has written the perfect answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569568/shopping-cart-persistence-session-or-browser-cookie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest storing the shopping cart items in the user's *session* (`$_SESSION` variables). If you need them to persist across sessions, put them in a database table.

In session variables, they're safe from tampering (they're on the server side) and you don't have to worry about information disclosure (all that's in the cookie or `GET` parameter is the session ID).

Comment: How would you suggest storing the items and quantities in the cart in the database? Obviously these parameters cannot be determined before hand, so I can't create a column for each item in the cart. Should I serialize the data and store that in a column, then have another column that has the session id?

Comment: @user1197328 If you link them to the session ID, then when the session expires they're gone. You can store the cart items and quantities with just three columns - `user_id`, `item_id`, and `quantity`. The `user_id` tells you whose shopping cart you're looking at, and each row in the table is one type of item they have in their cart.

Comment: I see. So in order for the shopping cart to remain available to a visitor I would need to use a cookie to link the guest to their shopping cart? You suggest using three columns for the table; does that mean I would have one row in the table for each item the visitor has in their cart? Is that more efficient than having all the items and quantities in one column using a comma separated list or serializing it? THANKS for your help!

Comment: @user1197328 No, I'm saying that for a shopping cart to remain available to a user who no longer kept their session - ie discarded their cookies - you need to store the session in the DB associated with their user ID (registered users only). If they clear their cookies and have no account, you won't have a cart for them. **Yes**, storing one row per entry is much much better than putting multiple items into one column. Look at http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/ for information on normal forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SESSION to store the Items Id and Quantity. On the check out page when the user submits/confirms order you can get the item value from DB against the item Id and calculate the actual Price for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a database store them in a database. 
If you have guest shopping, store them in a temp_cart where you link that guest to a session variable.

Look up $_SESSION.